# Probability of Winning a Toss

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have an unfair coin with two sides 1 and 2.

I have a problem and its constraints.

The coin has to be tossed until I win; which happens when 1 shows up in a toss.

Constraints:
Since the coin in unfair, I have to toss the coin at least X times. However, I am assured that if toss the coin at most Y times I will win; where Y >= X and Y is not equal to infinity.

Find the probability of me winning the game.

#### EDIT:

Adding a few more details. The purpose of this puzzle is to decide the easiness of the game. There are only two outcomes of the same; easy/difficult. The toughness of the game is decided upon a coin toss. I want to set the cut off Probability such that the user has to play this level at least X times in difficult mode, before an easy mode is selected.

Is it possible to decide this value mathematically?

Comment: If the tosses are independent, no one can assure you that if you toss $Y$ or fewer times you will win. At most they can say that you will win with probability say $0.99$.  If possible, the situation should be described more precisely.

Comment: All that follows from the constraints is that you must toss the coin at least once to win, and there is a nonzero probability of winning.   Therefore the probability is between 0 and 1.  In other words, your constraints only preclude the possibility of a one sided coin.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i have elaborated the problem further; any insights would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The constraint "if toss the coin at most Y times I will win" *almost* makes no sense. If the probability of getting a $2$ is non-zero, for any $Y$ there is a non-zero probability of getting all $2$'s on all $Y$ tries.

So if your statement is true, the probability of getting a $2$ must be zero, so you are guaranteed to win. The probability of you winning the game is $1$.

This solution does not seem right. Are you sure you typed the problem correctly?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've added more details above.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want a uniform distribution starting at 0 that takes a value of 0 prior to X, and 1 after Y. This isn't possible, however you can create a uniform distribution on (X, Y], and have a probability of 0 for all values of n < X:

P(n = 1) := {0 | n < X}, {1 | n >= Y}, {(n-X)/(Y-X) | X <= n <= Y}